# If your dictionary doesn't support you (or me), what should I do?

Tags: support

Recently I answered [**like this.**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/232933/affection-vs-affliction)

What came to my mind first when reading the OP's question was, that the meaning of the word "affection" should be Merriam's

> 1
>   :  any moderate feeling or emotion

But second thought came to my mind, "wait!,there is a different meaning for affection", which is according to Merriam,

> 3
>   a (1) :  a bodily condition (2) :  disease, malady

But unlike other users' answer, the Merriam doesn't label that meaning as archaic.

In such case, what do you think is the best strategy not to make a mistake?

Thank you for any support.

Comment: I really don't know what to say. It is a technical word in medicine and that's it. However, the 27 upvotes suggest people do not know that. There is nothing one can do in these cases. It has happened to me, too.